# How to get the pending queue sizes in Apache Storm?

Tags: performance, queue, monitor, apache-storm

I am working on the Apache Storm. I want to know is there a way to get the pending queue sizes in Apache Storm.

So I want to build a monitor system to identify load on the topology/bolt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ITaskHook to count the number of tuples written to and read from each stream.  The specifics of the API will tell you which specific task ids are sending and receiving each tuple.  It's just a matter of math to count the backlog.

You can see my open source monitor implementation that does exactly this at https://github.com/chrisGerken/gumbo

Answer (score 0):

SpoutOutputCollector has method `getPendingCount()`, which returns number of current pending messages.